# Yii2 Basic - How I set config for send mail using ec2 amazon server SES and SwiftMailer

Tags: amazon-ec2, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app, amazon-ses

Actually first i used Gmail SMTP its working. recently i have shifted my code on ec2 aws and it seemed email functionality is not working.please explain in detail how to Sending emails from ec2 using SES and SwiftMailer in Yii2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set the mailer config as follows

```
   'mailer' => [
        'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
        'useFileTransport'=>false,
        'transport' => [
            'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
            'host' => '',// amazon smtp host 
            'username' => '',// ses user username
            'password' => '',// ses user password
            'port' => '587',
            'encryption' => 'tls',
            ],
    ],
```

you need to create ses-smtp IAM user  or attach the following "AmazonSesSendingAccess" Policy to an existing user